# Json schema validation in soapUI using groovy

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, jsonschema

I have encountered the problem with the Json response validation in soapUI. I have service, that returns json responses, I hve schema for this service. 
1. Can I use the Json schema in soapUI? If yes, then how? (All my attempts to configure it was failed)
2. Can I perform validation using the groovy scripts? I have found several possible solutions in internet (gitHub), but I got the errors when try to run the scripts.

Such scripts as:
1.
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText("""\
        {
            "givenName" : "Alexander",
            "familyName" : "De Leon"
        }
    """)

```
use(JsonSchema){
    json.schema  = 'http://json-schema.org/card'
    assert json.conformsSchema()
}
```

douesn't work. I am getting the error: No such property JsonSchema for class.

1. Using the scripts as described here, gives also no results: http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=24829&p=57104&hilit=schema&sid=695d82ac14104f727529196faecca2e4#p57104

Error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script29.eval()

If some one performs validation of Json responses in soapUI using groovy, or any other approaches, then could you please share your experience?

Thanks!